# Filter Out All Entries But Latest Date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, filter

I have three tables I'm querying out of an Oracle database.  Here are the tables with their contents I'm trying to access:

patient table:
Visit Number, Pat_Seq

med_admin table:
Pat_Seq, Drug_ID, Dose_Given, Administered_Time

Drug Table:
Drug_Name, Drug_ID

I need to pull the Drug.Drug_Name, Med_Admin.Dose_Given, Med_Admin.Administered_Time but I also need to filter it down to the Med_Admin.Drug_ID with the most recent date.

The way my boss put it is "I need a list of patient medications with the most recent date/time given.  Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT to_char(a.administered_time, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Administered Date",
d.drug_name AS "Drug Name"
FROM med_admin a
JOIN drug d ON a.drug_id = d.drug_id
WHERE a.drug_id IN(select distinct(d.drug_id) from drug d)
```

Whenever I add the Med_Admin.Administered_Time it adds rows for every med given.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do you need the latest drug administered for one patient or for all.

Comment: I need the latest drug administered for one patient, I drill that down by joining the patient table and searching by the visit number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this query should get you the details of all patients latest medication.

```
SELECT 
    to_char(a.administered_time, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Administered Date",
    d.drug_name AS "Drug Name"
FROM med_admin a
    JOIN drug d ON a.drug_id = d.drug_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM med_admin b 
                  WHERE a.Pat_Seq = b.Pat_Seq
                      AND b.administered_time > a.administered_time)
```

Essentially we are saying, if there `EXISTS` a drug, administered to the same patient that has a `administered_time` more than the current row's `administered_time`, then do `NOT` select the row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already specified the JOIN drug d ON a.drug_id = d.drug_id, you do not need the where clause in order to join Med_Admin with Drug:

```
WHERE a.drug_id IN(select distinct(d.drug_id) from drug d)
```

Conderning your query, you can try something like:

```
SELECT a.Dose_Given
AS
  "Dose Given", TO_CHAR(a.administered_time, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AS
  "Administered Date", b.Drug_Name
AS
  "Drug Name" FROM Med_Admin a left join Drug b ON a.drug_id=b.drug_id WHERE
  a.Administered_Time  =
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(Administered_Time)
    FROM
      Med_Admin c
    WHERE
      c.Drug_ID=a.Drug_ID
  )
```